# incomplete type name in nested name specifier

Tags: c++, class, friend

I have the following two classes, and I want to specify one of the methods of the second class as a friend of the first so as that method has access to it's variables. I've tried the following in my header:

```
class SequenceThreader;

enum MappingDirection {Nowhere, Forward, Backwards};

class SequenceMapping {
    friend void SequenceThreader::query_paths_to_fasta(std::ofstream& output_file) const;
private:
    seqID_t seq_id;
    int32_t first_seq_pos;
    int32_t last_seq_pos;
    sgNodeID_t node;
    int32_t first_node_pos;
    int32_t last_node_pos;
    int32_t matched_unique_kmers;
    uint64_t possible_unique_matches;
    uint64_t n_kmers_in_node;
    bool direction_will_continue(int32_t next_position) const;

public:
    SequenceMapping();
    bool operator==(const SequenceMapping &other);
    bool operator<(const SequenceMapping &other) const;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const SequenceMapping& sm);
    void initiate_mapping(uint64_t sequence_id);
    bool ismatched();
    void start_new_mapping(const graphPosition& gpos, int32_t seqpos, const UniqueKmerIndex& counts);
    void extend(int32_t nodepos, int32_t seqpos);
    sgNodeID_t absnode() const;
    sgNodeID_t dirnode() const;
    int32_t n_unique_matches() const;
    MappingDirection node_direction() const;
    MappingDirection seq_direction() const;
    bool mapping_continues(const graphPosition& gpos) const;
    double POPUKM() const;
};

class SequenceThreader {
    typedef std::unordered_map<seqID_t, std::vector<SequenceMapping>> SequenceMappingStore;
    typedef std::unordered_map<seqID_t, std::vector<std::vector<SequenceMapping>>> SequenceMappingPathsStore;

private:
    SequenceGraph& sg;
    UniqueKmerIndex graph_kmer_index;

    uint8_t k;
    std::string query_seq_file;
    std::string output_prefix;
    uint64_t memory_limit;
    SequenceMappingStore mappings_of_sequence;
    SequenceMappingPathsStore paths_of_mappings_of_sequence;

    void map_sequences_from_file(uint64_t min_matches, const std::string& filename);
    std::set<SequenceGraphPath> all_unique_paths() const;
    void print_mapping_path_name(const std::vector<SequenceMapping>& path, std::ofstream& output_file) const;

public:
    explicit SequenceThreader(SequenceGraph &_sg, uint8_t _k = 31) : sg(_sg), k(_k), graph_kmer_index(sg, _k) {}

    void map_sequences(uint64_t min_matches, const std::string& filename, const std::string& output) {
        output_prefix = output;
        query_seq_file = filename;

        map_sequences_from_file(min_matches, filename);
    }

    void print_mappings() const;
    void mappings_paths();
    void print_paths() const;
    void graph_paths_to_fasta(std::ofstream& output_file) const;
    void query_paths_to_fasta(std::ofstream& output_file) const;
    void print_unique_paths_sizes(std::ofstream& output_file) const;
};
```

But I'm getting a compile error:

```
In file included from /Users/bward/github/bsg/src/sglib/SequenceThreader.cpp:8:
/Users/bward/github/bsg/src/sglib/SequenceThreader.h:22:17: error: incomplete type 'SequenceThreader' named in nested name specifier
    friend void SequenceThreader::query_paths_to_fasta(std::ofstream& output_file) const;
```

Which stumps me, since the friend declaration docs here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend

Say something like `friend char* X::foo(int); // members of other classes can be friends too` is fine.

What do I need to do to get this to compile?

Comment: Aaaah! I see so the compiler knows from my forward decl that the class exists, but knows nothing about it's query_paths_to_fasta method yet. Thanks songyuanyao, do you want to make an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SequenceThreader` has to be defined firstly, only forward declaration is not enough. As the error message said `SequenceThreader` needs to be complete type here, otherwise the compiler can't know that `SequenceThreader` has such a member named `query_paths_to_fasta` or not.

To solve the issue you could move the definition of `SequenceThreader` ahead (and remove the forward declaration).